# Android Navigation Components popupto logic with shared screens

Tags: android, android-architecture-navigation

So I have an interesting flow of screens in our app.  Feature A and Feature B with a shared end flow at the end.  I am not sure best practices for implementing the popupto in the navigation graph
So feature A's flow goes like this
Main - > Feature A Screen 1,Feature A Screen 2, Shared Flow Screen 1, Shared Flow Screen 2.

I want to popupto Feature A Screen 1 when launching Shared end flow Screen 2.  Which is obvious when you are not doing a shared end flow.  But lets say I had another flow like
Main - > Feature B Screen 1,Feature B Screen 2, Shared Flow Screen 1, Shared Flow Screen 2.

I am not able to set popupto to Feature B Screen 1 and Feature A Screen 1 in the nav graph.

I have thought of different solutions but are not sure on best practices

1. Put Feature A and B into a nested nav graph where popupto the whole nav graph not inclusive and deep link
2. Dynamically change the nested nav graph start destination to Feature A or B and popup to the nav graph.
3. Have 2 different nav graphs for the 2 flows and for the different nav graphs have different popuptos
4. Pass popupto param to the nav graph to say where to go back
5. Somehow inspect the nav graph to identify where they came from and popupto via code.

Any blog articles on this or what do you think you would do in this situation.  I am not sure if all of these situations would work but I am exploring 3 but it will require duplication of nav graph code.

Answer (score 0):

I also was unable to find an elegant solution to the problem, but I was able to get the desired result by adding a intermediate screen, which immediately forwards to the shared screen. I could then popUpTo that fragment, with popUpToInclusive set to true. I hope this might be helpful.